# Counting Problem in Probability with a 2D Object

Tags: probability

I have an octagon. I randomly place points on the edges
of this octagon such that each point on the boundary of the
octagon is equally likely to be chosen. I want to figure out
the probability that if I place a line through the middle of
the octagon (as in, after I place the line, the two sides of the
octagon are symmetric on the line), all of the points will be on
one half of the octagon split by the line. To me, I really have
no idea how to start building the probabilistic model for this
problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not specify, but the mention of symmetry sort of indicates you have a regular octagon in mind. It is a coin flipping model.  The situation is different if we ask whether *there is a line* through the centre such that all the points are on one side or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of splitting the octagon first, then picking the points.  The first point can go anywhere and have all the points in the same half.  All the other points have to go in that half.